# How to convert to string from number after a sql action in logic apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm querying data from an external SQL source thru logic apps. I have no control over this external source, I have read access only. This source returns the data in a JSON array the way I expect it to be, numbers, strings etc.

However when I pass on the result set to the next (compose) action, the numbers are converted to a scientific markup and arrive this way at the input side of the action. I.e. 2957677486919385600 becomes 2.9576774869193856E+18. I don't seem to get the chance to convert the value properly before it arrives at the next action. I'm guessing this has something to do with the datatype of origin, which is a number.

The obvious solution would be to adjust my sql query and convert the data to a string at the data source side (I've tested it, this works), but I don't want to do this because of the amount of data and the load it causes at the data source.

Is there a way to transform this number into a string so I can process it further in it's original format?

Comment: Have you tried CAST() in the query itself?  Like SELECT CAST(MyHugeNumber as varchar(50)) as StringNumber….

Comment: @Johns-305 I've already tried this and I'm hoping there's a way to avoid this solution. I feel like it should be possible to handle this conversion on the LogicApp side.

Answer (score 0):

As Johns said, you could sue `CAST()` when you execute sql query.

Here is the sql query Statement:`select CAST(num as varchar(50)) as NumToString from Table1`.

And the output snapshot:

[image]

For more details about CAST() you could refer to this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp).